# Applescript/automator : move all the files listed in a document

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes, file-handling, automator

I'm completely rebuilding a shared iTunes library and this needs to be team work.
I found a way to work the XML database in Google Drive so that we can all edit the track list simultaneously (>7500 entries). The spreadsheet contains for every song the path to the corresponding file.

Now I need a script to move the tracks listed in that spreadsheet to a common folder, so I can separate the songs we decided to keep from the ones we don't want anymore.

The blueprint I imagined for the code is basically :

1. Get the paths list (txt, csv, etc. doesn't matter) and store it as
   an array.
2. Rotate through that array and select+move  to a common folder each file pointed by the paths.

I'm not expecting any ready-to-use solution, but I would really appreciate some tips or pieces of advice that could make me spare a lot of time.

I also have to admit I have limited knowledge in Mac OS X programming (more used to web and windows environments) and have no experience in Applescripts.
However, I feel that what I'm trying to achieve is pretty straightforward and could help other people as well.

Comment: Can you show the format of file you are generating?

Answer (score 0):

there are just 2 items not clear in your request :

1) what is the file type in which file paths are stored ? I assumed it is a text file
2) which format the paths have ? is it Unix format (like HD/Users/My_User/Desktop/My_Song), or is is a Finder format (like HD:Users:My_User:Desktop:My_Song). I assume it is a finder format

then script bellow asks you to select the text file, read it, ask you to select destination folder and move every file described in text file to the destination folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
set TextFile to (choose file with prompt "Select your text file" of type {"txt"})
set My_Folder to choose folder with prompt "Select your destination folder"
set List_files to paragraphs of (read TextFile)
move List_files to My_Folder
end tell
```

the "move" can be changed to a "copy", if required

Comment: to convert unix path to Finder path, standard instruction "posix file" can be used: Set A to posix file B.  it will convert unix path B into Finder path in A.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to both of you for your answers.

Regarding pbell's questions :
1. I did not specify the format of the file containing the paths because I wasn't sure which ones the script could handle. Now I will make sure it is in a txt format.
2. The paths are actually il a Unix format, but seeing your example it looks pretty easy to parse. Can I just replace every "/" with a ":" ..?

I will try your code this afternoon. Again thanks a lot for caring and for sharing your time and knowledge.

Terence

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm !

Thank you very much pbell, your code works perfectly. I just had to make a txt file with Finder-formatted paths like so :

```
Macintosh HD:Users:FirstnameSurname:Desktop:Music:November-7:Season 3:04 Parasite.mp3
Macintosh HD:Users:FirstnameSurname:Desktop:Music:November-7:Season 3:05 Nowhere.mp3
Macintosh HD:Users:FirstnameSurname:Desktop:Music:November-7:Season 3:06 Amber Light.mp3
```

We spared so much time thanks to you.

Have a great day,
Terence